# Run Solr on tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

is it possible to run Solr 6.4.1 on tomcat?
I read that Solr does not support tomcat anymore, is that true, if yes is there any other option without tomcat?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any version of Solr from 5 and onwards does not support Tomcat as an alternative officially.

The reasoning for this has [been documented on the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar):

> Solr is intended to be a server not a Java web application, similar to mysql or the Apache web server. When Solr was first created, designing it as a web application was a convenient choice, to avoid writing a lot of tricky code to build a network layer. These days, this design decision has become a limiting factor.
>
> When you download Solr and install it onto your machine, it should be Solr that gets started. It should not be necessary to install Solr into a third-party application (servlet container) before it will work.
>
> At this time, Solr is still a webapp, but this is an internal implementation detail, not an immutable property. The intention is to make Solr into a completely standalone application. Startup scripts that start the included container are the first step towards that goal. Jetty might still be the technology used once Solr is a standalone application, but if that happens, it will be internally embedded.

At the moment you can still attempt to run Solr in a different container, as the current version bundles jetty and loads Solr inside jetty, but you can run into unexplainable issues where you'll always suspect the container to be the issue .. and if you have a problem, reporting bugs while running under Tomcat won't do any good.

From [one of the comments on the old tomcat page on the community wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat):

> If you want to go against recommendations and run 5.3 or later in Tomcat, you can likely still do so, but you will need to inform tomcat about an exploded web application (found in server/solr-webapp) instead of the .war file.
>
> The server/solr_webapp/webapp folder is an exploded web application. Tomcat documentation should be able to tell you how to add such an application.

.. but if you're deploying Solr now, you really shouldn't. Use the bundled version of jetty (which might change to a stand alone version later) and the `solr` command / script.

Answer (score 0):

They have stopped the support for the same.

Other option could be, you can check out the code and see if you can build the solr. I had tried it for earlier version (3.3).

I am not sure of the current version. But that could be the option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted instructions on how to get solr 6.2 running on Tomcat [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Running-Solr-6-3-on-Tomcat-Help-Please-td4320874.html). However, these instructions no longer work on Solr 6.3 or 6.4.